# Reference request on the basics of differential operators and symbols

Tags: reference-request, differential-operators

Perhaps it is too much to ask, but I'm searching for some published article or book, to cite some results from it, that treats infinite degree differential opertors (with constant coefficients) and its symbols, but in an elementary level. Elementary in the sense that I'm working with analytic function and polynomials on finite dimensional vector spaces. (I'm not even applying differential operators to differential equations.)

The problems so far with the books that I have found is that they are very abstract in their treatment, or that they treat only the case of finite degree differential operators.

I'm sorry if there is a canonical reference for this topic which I have not found, but this is area is new to me.

Comment: Umbral calculus often deals with diff ops of infinite degree, e.g., typical raising / creation ops. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191752/whats-umbral-calculus-about/1085165